# Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000

Tags: javascript, mongodb, server

Hey everyone i am new here, trying to follow along a course on Udemy about connecting Node app to database, but stuck on a problem can't actually run the server using MongoDB database. Code is at the end.

The error

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1317:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1365:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1451:7)
    at Function.listen (C:\Users\Elev\Desktop\javapamokos\todolist\todolistonSteroids\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at C:\Users\Elev\Desktop\javapamokos\todolist\todolistonSteroids\server.js:10:5
    at C:\Users\Elev\Desktop\javapamokos\todolist\todolistonSteroids\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:674:5
    at C:\Users\Elev\Desktop\javapamokos\todolist\todolistonSteroids\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:225:7
    at connectCallback (C:\Users\Elev\Desktop\javapamokos\todolist\todolistonSteroids\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:366:5)
    at C:\Users\Elev\Desktop\javapamokos\todolist\todolistonSteroids\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:602:5
    at connectHandler (C:\Users\Elev\Desktop\javapamokos\todolist\todolistonSteroids\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:297:43)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1344:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}
```

code part 1 (https://prnt.sc/v8rnqm)
code part 2 (https://prnt.sc/v8rofm)

Comment: The port is already in use. Instead of app.listen(3000), change to app.listen(4575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 10 you already calling `app.listen(3000)`
and then (lines are hidden by screenshot) in the bottom of the file you are calling `app.listen(3000)` again. That's the reason, leave it on line 10 only. If you need this instance multiple times think about assigning it to a constant. For example:

```js
const socket_id = app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is for linux ubuntu users

```
killall -9 node
```